# Asynchronous function in JavaScript not updating variable at the same time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, asynchronous, react-hooks

I am trying to get the country that the user is in, then based on the country, I am initiating a useState called "FromCurrency". Everything is fetching successfully, the problem is that the asynchronous function (fetch is asynchronous), the FromCurrency is not updating immediately. I need to refresh my app one time to get the correct currency. What should I do?

```
const [fromCurrency, setFromCurrency] = useState('');
  const [country, setcountry] = useState('');


  useEffect(() => {

    (async () => {
      
      let { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync(); //Get Location of user

      if (status !== 'granted') 
      {
        setErrorMsg('Permission to access location was denied');
        return;
      }

      let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});

//Translate the coords (longitude, latitude) to country.
      const API_URL = `https://api.opencagedata.com/geocode/v1/json?q=${location["coords"]["latitude"]}%2C+${location["coords"]["longitude"]}&key=a6d141e0b2724551b1df99782db30631&pretty=1`;
      
      fetch(API_URL)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => 
      {
        console.log(json["results"][0]["components"]["country"]);
        setcountry(json["results"][0]["components"]["country"]);
        LocalCurrency(country)
      })
    })();  


const LocalCurrency = (country) => 
  {
    console.log("country", country);

    switch (country) 
    {
      case 'Sweden':
        setFromCurrency('SEK');
       break;
      default:
        setFromCurrency('USD');
        break;
    };
  };
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately `country` is stale when you call `LocalCurency`. `setcountry` doesn't (can't) modify the value of your `country` constant.

Comment: What do you mean by "*the FromCurrency is not updating immediately.*"? Where exactly in your code would you have expected it to be updated?

Comment: @Bergi I expect the fromCurrency to be updated when "LocalCurrency(country)" is invoked. I try to log inside of the LocalCurrency funtion but it dosen't log anything until I refresh/resave my code, then everything is working fine and the fromCurrency is updated.

Comment: @Program_Z Ah yes, I see now - the problem is that `country` (which you are passing to `LocalCurrency`) has not yet updated (it'll log the empty string), which leads to `fromCurrency` not updating. See the explanation below as well as the duplicate.

Comment: Regarding "*it works when I refresh my code*", that is only an artifact of hot reloading in your development environment. The code actually doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

setters in `useState` are asynchronous.
So you receive the response, set the country and directly try to use this new value from state (which will use the previous value, not the currently set one), not from response object.

The correct one should be

```
  fetch(API_URL)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => 
  {
    console.log(json["results"][0]["components"]["country"]);
    setcountry(json["results"][0]["components"]["country"]);
    LocalCurrency(json["results"][0]["components"]["country"])
  })
```

not

```
  fetch(API_URL)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => 
  {
    console.log(json["results"][0]["components"]["country"]);
    setcountry(json["results"][0]["components"]["country"]);
    LocalCurrency(country)
  })
```

Comment: he has `LocalCurrency(country)` not `LocalCurrency(json["results"][0]["components"]["country"])`

Comment: Ah! Thanks. That makes it a typo-level error in my book. Or a duplicate of any of the many "state setters are not synchronous" questions with answers, such as [the canonical one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately).

Comment: @Apostolos well I tried and it still dosen't instantly set my FromCurrency instantley. I need to "resave" my code one more time for it to work. I tried console logging inside of the LocalCurrency function (console.log("country", country);), but it dosen't log either, meaning that the function is not being called or invoked by LocalCurrency(json["results"][0]["components"]["country"]);

Comment: it uses directly the response from the API not the state value (which in your post will always be the previous value).

Comment: if this `console.log(json["results"][0]["components"]["country"])` returns a value, then this `LocalCurrency(json["results"][0]["components"]["country"])` should also log sth inside. then it's up to `switch` statement, if it handles it correctly.